# How can one gauge the popularity of a subject to be taken as a college major?

Tags: undergraduate

Essentially the title, if I am to say a statement like "Physics is more sought after as a major than Mathematics", what statistics could I use to justify or falsify it?

Comment: This question is probably off topic, but what do you mean by popularity? As a college major or as a career? Math is almost certainly more popular than Physics as a major, the (weak) evidence being the larger faculty sizes in math. The evidence is weak since the math department probably teaches more to non-majors than the physics department does, accounting partly for the difference in faculty size.

Comment: As a major, as in thr demand for it @Buffy

Comment: You might be able to find statistics about number of majors from university and professional society web sties. But why do you need this information? If choosing a major for yourself, your own interests should matter more than what other people think.

Comment: I'm trying to argue exactly what the type of statement I said in the subject to a friend lol :/

Comment: My undergrad uni (Waterloo, Ontario, Canada) had a huge math department and a mid-sized physics department. My grad uni (Toronto) had a huge physics department and a mid-sized math dept. How would you evaluate popularity in this case?

Answer (score 2):

> "Physics is more sought after as a major than Mathematics"

The American Mathematical Society [states](https://www.ams.org/profession/data/cbms-survey/chapter3.pdf) that 5,800 undergraduate math degrees were awarded in a one-year period circa 2004. The American Physical Society provides a [graph](https://www.aps.org/programs/education/statistics/bachelors.cfm), from which we can see that the number of physics degrees around the same time period was right around the same number. So, I'm gonna call this one a tie, or "within the margin of error."

Caveats:

- this is just the US
- the math number does not include those studying math education, statistics, or related fields (and the physics number probably does include many students primarily interested in astronomy). On the other hand, many types of engineering are mostly applied physics, whereas far fewer things are really "like" (pure) math.
- these numbers are quite old
- this is the number of *graduates*, not the number who "sought after" the major but were unable to finish.
- these are two different professional societies, so probably not exactly apples-to-apples in terms of methodology.

Comment: In general, professional societies in any field are likely to keep such statistics, though not apples-to-apples, as you say.